# Is using too many input fields in Angular reactive form makes the input fields sluggish?

Tags: angular

I am using reactive form which contains 8 groups and each group has at least 10 fields. some fields are FormArray. 
By using too many input fields it becomes sluggish and it has delay to respond when i type something.

Comment: for better performance, in Angular 5, you can use {UpdateOn:'blur'} or {UpdateOn:'submit'} if you needn't validate/update each "key" change

Comment: i have applied it but there is no improvement in performance

Comment: @Musbashir, then, I supouse the main problem is that you have a validator that take much time, or you have "calculated fileds". For the first case don't validate the fileds using validators, just in submit call to a function for validating and show the errors. for the second case, try use variables, nor fields that belong to the form